# If I go to a single onion service will the Tor Button notice the difference?

Tags: onion-services, tor-button

If I go to a standard onion service Tor button shows me,

Me <-> Guard (IP) <-> Middle (IP) <-> Exit (IP) <-> relay (without giving the IP) <-> relay <-> relay <-> onion service

But if I go to the new single onion services will the Tor Button notice the difference and wont show the 6 hops (only 3 hops)?

Answer (score 1):

No, Tor Button will not notice the difference.

Tor Button has absolutely no knowledge about what is going on beyond the third hop, the 3 extra relays displayed are just placeholders to illustrate the concept.

It could be the case that sometimes there are 0, 1 or 6 relays beyond the 3 that Tor Button knows about, it simply cannot know (which is the point of onion services).

Answer (score 1):

According to core Tor developer David Goulet, the Tor Button will notice the difference:

> [With the next generation onion service (we hope by mid-2017 so ~6 months), every onion service will advertise in its descriptor that it *is*
>   a single onion service and we hope to make the circuit viewer in Tor Browser
>   show that when visiting a single onion service.](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2016-December/042753.html)

Comment: Yes, the next gen onion services will have a line in the descriptor which indicates they're a single-onion service but that's just a line of text, it could be faked. Tor Button simply cannot know what is beyond the rendezvous point.